# How can I correct the alignment of an acronym expansion in a table?

Tags: tables, acronyms

I'm using  the package  *acronym* to  handle acronyms  in my
document. Unfortunately, when expanding  them inside a table
they become shifted downwards. Here's a minimal example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{LONG1}{My extra super long acronym}
  \acro{LONG2}{Yet another very long acronym}
\end{acronym}

\begin{tabular}{ | p{3cm} | p{3cm} |}
  \hline
  \ac{LONG1} & Line 1 \\ \hline
  \ac{LONG2} & Line 2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table example]

Ideally, I'd  like them  to be  aligned to  the top  and not
justified. How can I achieve that?

Comment: To suppress justification, be sure to load the `array` package and change `p{3cm}` to `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}`.

Comment: Thank you @Mico!

Comment: I have the same issue, but this response did not work. Any other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time an acronym is used, a line `\acronymused{...}` is written to the `aux` file. This introduces a *whatsit* node which doesn't behave well in vertical mode, like at the start of a `p` cell. You see the same behaviour here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\foo}{\write\@auxout{\@percentchar hello world}foo}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | }
\hline
\foo & Line 1 \\ \hline
\leavevmode\foo & Line 2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To avoid the problem you should start horizontal mode before using `\ac` by writing `\leavevmode` (or `\mbox{}`) at the start of the incriminated cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{LONG1}{My extra super long acronym}
  \acro{LONG2}{Yet another very long acronym}
\end{acronym}

\begin{tabular}{ | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | }
  \hline
  \leavevmode\ac{LONG1} & Line 1 \\ \hline
  \leavevmode\ac{LONG2} & Line 2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `acronym` package should either start its typesetting macros with `\leavevmode`, or move the `\write` after the acronym has been typeset.